# (Rails) How can I split PUT/PATCH requests on a resource to different actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails routing helpers effectively merge `PUT` and `PATCH` and map it to a resource update action:

```rb
resource :foo
# Both PUT and PATCH actions on /foo/some-id map to foos#update controller
```

I am building an API where I would like `PATCH /foo/some-id` to map to an `update` action, and `PUT /foo/some-id` to map to a `replace` action. This better tracks the HTTP spec for PUT and PATCH. However, I can't seem to use the routing helpers to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with:

```rb
resource :foo, except: :update do
  patch :update
  put :update, action: :replace
end
```